# 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable? Django

Tags: django

I'm creating a summary page of all the posts that user has created and returning those posts to the summary page. I get the error above?

It's complaining about this line:

```
uploaded_aircraft = Aircraft.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

**View**

```
def aircraft_create(request):
  form = aircraft_form(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.user = request.user
    instance.save()
    messages.success(request, "Your upload has been successfully added!")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
  else:
    messages.error(request, "There seems to be something wrong. Have a look again..!")
  context = {"form":form,}
  return render(request,'aircraft/aircraft_form.html', context)
```

**Model**

```
class Aircraft(AircraftModelBase):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    manufacturer = SortableForeignKey(Manufacturer)
    aircraft_type = SortableForeignKey(AircraftType)
```

**View**

```
def account_overview(request):
    fav_aircraft = FavoritedAircraft.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)
    fav_airline = FavoritedAirline.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)

    uploaded_aircraft = Aircraft.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    return render(request,'account/account_overview.html', {'favAircraft':fav_aircraft,
                                                             'favAirline':fav_airline,
                                                             'UploadedAircraft':uploaded_aircraft})
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/cserv1_a/soc_ug/sc13nh/env/v10/accounts/views.py", line 57, in account_overview
    uploaded_aircraft = Aircraft.objects.filter(user=request.user)
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/db/models/query.py", line 790, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/db/models/query.py", line 808, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1243, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1269, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1174, in build_filter
    self.check_related_objects(field, value, opts)
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1073, in check_related_objects
    for v in value:
  File "/home/csunix/scpython/lib/django/utils/functional.py", line 205, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

What seems to be actual problem here?

Comment: If you have an error, then please include the *full* traceback in your question.

Comment: @Alasdair Done!

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't need `user__id=request.user.id` in your other filters `user=request.user` should work fine (as long as the user is logged in).

Answer (score 20):

The error is telling you that `request.user` is an anonymous user. That means that they are not logged in, so it doesn't make sense to try to filter with `filter(user=request.user)`.

The easiest fix is to use the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator, to make sure that only logged-in users can access the view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def account_overview(request):
    ...
```

Comment: In my template I already had "{% if user.is_authenticated %} else "Please login"  After adding that line it returns a 404. How do I get the else to work? Does it go in the view or the template?

Comment: It's too late to do the check in the template -- the filter has already occured in the view. The `login_required` decorator redirects the user to the login page if they are not logged in. If your `LOGIN_URL` setting and login view are not correctly configured, then you might get a 404. If you can't fix that, then please ask a new question.

Answer (score 6):

def account_overview(request):

```
 if request.user.is_authenticated:  # Notice this condition
    fav_aircraft = FavoritedAircraft.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)
    fav_airline = FavoritedAirline.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)

    uploaded_aircraft = Aircraft.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'account/account_overview.html', {'favAircraft':fav_aircraft,
                                                         'favAirline':fav_airline,
                                                         'UploadedAircraft':uploaded_aircraft})
   return render(request,'account/account_overview.html')
```

This should fix your issue
wrapping the view in with is_authenticated conditional statement to return a context only if the user is authenticated .

Comment: Now I get **name 'request' is not defined**

Comment: Adding **self.request.user.is_authenticated** solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Although in your case it doesn't work (because you use methods instead of classes), you could solve this problem with **LoginRequiredMixin**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyView (LoginRequiredMixin, View):
     login_url = '/ login /'
     redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issues and solved it by logging out then signing again.

For now, I think this might be an easy fix.

Comment: your answer should be posted as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue few minutes ago. Found two ways to solve:

1. Implement @login_required at the top of the view. This way the user will be redirected to the login page if he isn't authenticated.
2. Write 'if request.user.is_authenticated' at the top of the view function. An else block should also be added at the bottom to render the login page instead.

I hope this becomes helpful